# WPF UserControl as Polygon

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I am very new at this WPF world, i have some experience in the classic Windows Desktop applications.
I am trying to create a custom UserControl polygon shaped.
I have tryied creating a Path Data and then setting the UserControl Opacity property to "0", but it makes transparent the whole UserControl.

For example, i have build this Polygon inside the user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="WindowsFormsApp2.UserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
Width="640" Height="480" Opacity="100">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Path Data="M-70.616296,46.859802 L7.3270039,-1.2587545 174.31959,52.958763 168.71134,98.185567 z" Fill="#FF2121D6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="138,114,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Opacity ="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see the user control is 640x480 so when i add code to the UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown event, it fires if clicking in ay position inside the 640x480 while i want only to fire when clicking inside the polygon.

I have been googling for a solution but i can't found any solution, ¿maybe what i want it's not possible?

Comment: What is the purpose of the control when there is only a Path in it? Use a Path directly.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, how do i do it?, i am novice in this world. The purpouse is to be able to use several diferent user controls to make something like a puzzle so every piece has is own behaviour. Think about the figure Yin-Yang.

Comment: You don't need UserControls. Path or Polygon are also UI elements that you can directly put in a container Panel, e.g. a Canvas. Please don't try to start WPF with no knowlegde at all. It really helps to read some introductory material, e.g. a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may template a `UserControl` to look like a polygon:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Path Data="M-70.616296,46.859802 L7.3270039,-1.2587545 174.31959,52.958763 168.71134,98.185567 z" 
                  Fill="#FF2121D6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="138,114,0,0" 
                  Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Opacity ="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="246"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Or you may just get rid of the `UserControl` and use the `Path` element directly. It also has a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event that you can handle.

Comment: Thx @mm8 i will check but seems that it is what i need. I want to make a library of user controls with diferent shapes, somthing like a puzzle.